# how to do 'check in' to code that uses Nuget package

Tags: c#, winforms, tfs, nuget

i want to do 'check in' to code uses Nuget package.
what is the the best way to do it?
Do i need to do 'check in' to the package folder? 
Is there any way to put the dll's (nuget's dlls) in GAC and add them public key token?
My solution is written in c# .net framework 4.5. TFS version - 2015
thanks!

Comment: I usually just check in the entire solution...

Answer (score 2):

You should not check in NuGet packages into TFS Version Control. As one of the advantages of using NuGet is that you can use it to avoid checking in binaries to your version control system.

In VS, you can enable package restore:

[image]

In TFS, you need to restore NuGet packages during TFS build process by adding a "Nuget Package Restore" task to your build, and the required packages will be downloaded.

[image]

More information, refer to this article: https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore